# How to get touch point outside current app

Tags: swift

I want to develop one iOS app. Is there any way to get the ui touch point when app in background. Like i want tap randomly in iOS device screen and my app will get correspond touch point accordingly.

Comment: This kind of functionality is not provided by iOS so can't be able to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, this is not possible on iOS.

Comment: Upvote for "*fortunately*", in case you meant it that way.